# Restoring NTFS permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, cifs, netapp

I have two large file shares where the following has occurred:

1. A (currently unknown) administrator took ownership of the share.
2. The administrator broke inheritance on the share, and removed the inherited permissions.
3. The administrator granted a security principal modify permissions on the share.

I need to re-enable inheritance on the share to fix the issue, but I cannot do that without taking ownership. I can't take ownership without risk of destroying explicit permissions assigned deeper in the share. Currently, the Owner tab states 'Unable to display current owner.'

Each share is a cifs share on NetApp storage.

Does anyone know of a way to discover who the current owner is in case we can't get the offending party to fess up? If I can get the current owner to switch the owner for me, I think I can avoid the destructive side effects of taking ownership myself. Then I can send that admin to the corner to think about what he or she has done...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in **Powershell** you can install [Powershell Community Extensions (PSCX)][1] and use their `Get-Privilege` and `Set-Privilege` cmdlets.

```
$p = Get-Privilege
$p.Enable('SeRestorePrivilege')
```

Now you can browse to the problem directory and see who owns it, and even change it.

Comment: After executing the above without error, Get-Privilege reveals I still do not have SeRestorePrivilege enabled and I still cannot view owner on the folder in question.

Edit: I don't know what Identity is used by default. If I execute Get-Privilege -identity <MyAdminAccount>, it reveals I already have SeRestorePrivilege enabled. But I cannot view owner.

Comment: Make sure you are running PowerShell as administrator.

Comment: I am running PowerShell as administrator. I edited comment above before I saw your response. Get-Privilege -Identity <adminAccount> reveals my admin account already has SeRestorePrivilege (and all others) enabled.